# Does appender-ref in logback config file support wild card?

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

Does the appender-ref support using wildcard, such as below, which ref="command-*"? I want the dispatchingAppender refers to multiple appenders with name starting with "command-". Any idea or suggestions?

```
<!-- Dispatcher appender - entry point required for ESG logging subsystem -->
<appender name="dispatchingAppender"
    class="com.test.jmx.log.logback.DispatchingAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="exception-*" />
    <appender-ref ref="command-*" />
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported, but you could look into writing a patch.  It's probably not too hard, but I'm not sure.